# How do I get contours from a scanned map?

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff

I have a scanned map which is a .tif file. I have geo-referenced it, and now I want to render it in 2.5D. Can i do this in QGIS? The ENC file is not available for the map I am using. The map already has contour lines on it, it is a colored sea map with black lines for contours. Land is denoted in yellow and green. Unfortunately due to company policy I cannot upload it.

Comment: What sort of map?  Is it a grey-scale or colour height map, a 'traditional' map with roads and contour lines, something else?  The technique will vary depending on type (a picture would help).  Regardless of type, unless you absolutely have to, this is probably not your best approach as, depending on location, there are probably sources of height data that will be less effort to acquire and will give a much more accurate result.  But to get help with that, we'd need to know the location.  Please edit your question to make it more specific.

Comment: Height Data is unavailable, but contours are there on the map.

Comment: Height data is available globally from a variety of sources.  As for edge extraction, this question has been answered a number of times.